# How can I translate a Spark Client submitApplication to Yarn Rest API?

Tags: java, rest, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Currently I have a working code implementation of submitting an application to Yarn using **spark.deploy.yarn.Client**. It's complex to aggregate all the arguments this client needs, but the submission of the application is simple:

```
ClientArguments cArgs = new ClientArguments(args.toArray(new String[0]));
client = new Client(cArgs, sparkConf);
applicationID = client.submitApplication();
```

Most of the code before this point was accumulating the **sparkConf** and **args**. Now I wish to retire the **Client** and work with Rest only. Spark offers a full REST api including submitting applications - according to the [Spark documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Applications_APISubmit_Application) it's a matter of this easy json/xml post:

```
POST http://<rm http address:port>/ws/v1/cluster/apps
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "application-id":"application_1404203615263_0001",
  "application-name":"test",
  "am-container-spec":
{
  "local-resources":
  {
    "entry":
    [
      {
        "key":"AppMaster.jar",
        "value":
        {
          "resource":"hdfs://hdfs-namenode:9000/user/testuser/DistributedShell/demo-app/AppMaster.jar",
          "type":"FILE",
          "visibility":"APPLICATION",
          "size": 43004,
          "timestamp": 1405452071209
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "commands":
  {
    "command":"{{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java -Xmx10m org.apache.hadoop.yarn.applications.distributedshell.ApplicationMaster --container_memory 10 --container_vcores 1 --num_containers 1 --priority 0 1><LOG_DIR>/AppMaster.stdout 2><LOG_DIR>/AppMaster.stderr"
  },
  "environment":
  {
    "entry":
    [
      {
        "key": "DISTRIBUTEDSHELLSCRIPTTIMESTAMP",
        "value": "1405459400754"
      },
      {
        "key": "CLASSPATH",
        "value": "{{CLASSPATH}}<CPS>./*<CPS>{{HADOOP_CONF_DIR}}<CPS>{{HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}}/share/hadoop/common/*<CPS>{{HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}}/share/hadoop/common/lib/*<CPS>{{HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}}/share/hadoop/hdfs/*<CPS>{{HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}}/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*<CPS>{{HADOOP_YARN_HOME}}/share/hadoop/yarn/*<CPS>{{HADOOP_YARN_HOME}}/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*<CPS>./log4j.properties"
      },
      {
        "key": "DISTRIBUTEDSHELLSCRIPTLEN",
        "value": "6"
      },
      {
        "key": "DISTRIBUTEDSHELLSCRIPTLOCATION",
        "value": "hdfs://hdfs-namenode:9000/user/testuser/demo-app/shellCommands"
      }
    ]
  }
},
"unmanaged-AM":false,
"max-app-attempts":2,
"resource":
{
  "memory":1024,
  "vCores":1
},
"application-type":"YARN",
"keep-containers-across-application-attempts":false,
"log-aggregation-context":
{
  "log-include-pattern":"file1",
  "log-exclude-pattern":"file2",
  "rolled-log-include-pattern":"file3",
  "rolled-log-exclude-pattern":"file4",
  "log-aggregation-policy-class-name":"org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AllContainerLogAggregationPolicy",
  "log-aggregation-policy-parameters":""
},
"attempt-failures-validity-interval":3600000,
"reservation-id":"reservation_1454114874_1",
"am-black-listing-requests":
{
  "am-black-listing-enabled":true,
  "disable-failure-threshold":0.01
}
}
```

I tried to translate my arguments into this JSON body of the POST request, but it seems impossible. Does anyone know if I can reverse-engineer from a running application I submitted the JSON payload to send via REST? Or what mapping I could use to take the Client arguments and place them in the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little searching, I managed to submit an application from the REST API only. It's not a well-documented process, so I'm posting it here.

**NOTE:** if at any time you wish to compare the content of the request to the request sent by the client, use debug breakpoints to inspect the application context used by the Client. 
Open the class `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl` and go to the method `submitApplication(ApplicationSubmissionContext appContext)`.

Firstly, to replace the `spark.deploy.yarn.Client` with a REST API request, the solution must make sure all the files mentioned in the configuration are available on the HDFS. 
Later, it needs to compose and upload one extra file called `__spark_conf__.zip`.

**Step 1**

Go over the files from the `SparkConf` (the `Client`'s 2nd argument): files mentioned in "*AllJars*" tag, file mentioned in "*mainJarPath*", and files mentioned in "*FilesList*".

For each file, check if it exists in the HDFS and if not - upload it from the local machine. For each file get its `FileStatus` from the HDFS. 
aggregate the resources list, which is an attribute map for each file containing these 6 attributes:

- size = getLen()
- timestamp = getModificationTime()
- type=FILE
- visibility=PUBLIC

Two other attributes: key and resource.

- Files from the allJars list: Key is **spark_libs**/{{filename}}, and the resource is the filename.
- Files from the FilesList: key is "localEntry" tag, resource is "hdfsPath" tag.
- the File in mainJarPath: key is "**app**.jar", resource is the filename.

**Step 2**

Creating the `__spark_conf__.zip` file. You can create it directly in the hdfs, in the staging path which is usually `{{HDFS_base_folder}}/user/{{username}}/.sparkStaging/{{application_id}}/__spark_conf__.zip`.
This archive file contains two files and one empty directory: one file `__spark_hadoop_conf__.xml` (a rename to `core-site.xml`), and the other file is called `__spark_conf__.properties` which is a slightly modified version 
of the *sparkConf* section from the configuration.

To create `__spark_conf__.properties` you will need to read the JSON map from "*sparkConf"->"org$apache$spark$SparkConf$$settings*", and convert each line from the JSON format *"spark.safemine.addcontrol.driverMemory": "5120M"* 
to *spark.safemine.addcontrol.driverMemory=5120M*

To the bottom of the file add 6 new lines:

- spark.yarn.cache.confArchive={{the location to which you will upload `__spark_conf__.zip` in the sparkStaging}}
- spark.yarn.cache.visibilities={{all the visibilities of the files, comma delimited - basically "PUBLIC,PUBLIC, ... ,PUBLIC"}}
- spark.yarn.cache.timestamps={{All the timestamps for the files, comma delimited}}
- spark.yarn.cache.types={{all the types of the files, comma delimited - basically "FILE,FILE, ... ,FILE"}}
- spark.yarn.cache.filenames={{All the filenames and keys, recorded as resource#key and comma delimited}}
- spark.yarn.cache.sizes={{All the sizes for the files, comma delimited}}

Make sure you compile the 5 aggregated lines in respective order. I used this code:

```
    String confArchive = "spark.yarn.cache.confArchive="+hdfs+"/user/"+userName+"/.sparkStaging/"+applicationId+"/__spark_conf__.zip";
    String filenames = "spark.yarn.cache.filenames=";
    String sizes = "spark.yarn.cache.sizes=";
    String timestamps = "spark.yarn.cache.timestamps=";
    String types = "spark.yarn.cache.types=";
    String visibilities = "spark.yarn.cache.visibilities=";
    for (Map<String,String> localResource:localResources) {
        filenames+=localResource.get("resource")+"#"+localResource.get("key")+",";
        sizes+=localResource.get("size")+",";
        timestamps+=localResource.get("timestamp")+",";
        types+=localResource.get("type")+",";
        visibilities+=localResource.get("visibility")+",";

    }
    properties+=confArchive+"\n";
    properties+=filenames.substring(0,filenames.length()-1)+"\n";
    properties+=sizes.substring(0,sizes.length()-1)+"\n";
    properties+=timestamps.substring(0,timestamps.length()-1)+"\n";
    properties+=types.substring(0,types.length()-1)+"\n";
    properties+=visibilities.substring(0,visibilities.length()-1)+"\n";
```

The `__spark_hadoop_conf__.xml` file is a simple rename of `core-site.xml`, and the folder created with them is named `__hadoop_conf__` and is left empty.

you can save the files to the hdfs directly like so:

```
private void generateSparkConfInHdfs(String applicationId, String userName, String sparkConfProperties, String sparkHadoopConf) throws IOException {
    String path = hdfs+"/user/"+userName+"/.sparkStaging/"+applicationId+"/__spark_conf__.zip";
    Path hdfsPath = new Path(path);
    ZipOutputStream os = new ZipOutputStream(getHdfs().create(hdfsPath));
    os.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("__hadoop_conf__/"));
    os.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("__spark_conf__.properties"));
    os.write(sparkConfProperties.getBytes(),0,sparkConfProperties.getBytes().length);
    os.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("__spark_hadoop_conf__.xml"));
    os.write(sparkHadoopConf.getBytes(),0,sparkHadoopConf.getBytes().length);
    os.close();
}
```

After you finish creating the file, add it to the resources list with these specifications:

- size = getLen()
- timestamp = getModificationTime()
- type = ARCHIVE
- visibility = PRIVATE
- key = `__spark_conf__`
- resource is the staging directory (usually `{{HDFS_base_folder}}/user/{{username}}/.sparkStaging/{{application_id}}/__spark_conf__.zip`).

Go over the full resources list and create an XML/JSON from them with this structure for each one, using the values we collected in the {{}} placeholders:

```
    <entry>
        <key>{{key}}</key>
        <value>
            <resource>{{resource}}</resource>
            <size>{{size}}</size>
            <timestamp>{{timestamp}}</timestamp>
            <type>{{type}}</type>
            <visibility>{{visibility}}</visibility>
        </value>
    </entry>
```

The accumulated string will be your `localResources` XML segment shown below.

**Step 3**

Generating the Java command. You will need to extract a few elements from the SparkConfig:

- driverMemory - from the same attribute in the `sparkConf`
- extraJavaOptions = from `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` within the attribute collection
- mainClass - from the same attribute in the `sparkConf`
- argstr - collect all the `ClientArgs` except the --class one.

The result command with the elements included is:

```
String command = "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -server -Xmx"+driverMemory+" -Djava.io.tmpdir=$PWD/tmp "+extraJavaOptions+" -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=&lt;LOG_DIR&gt; "
            + "org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster --class "+mainClass+" "+argstr+" "
            + "--properties-file $PWD/__spark_conf__/__spark_conf__.properties 1&gt; &lt;LOG_DIR&gt;/stdout 2&gt; &lt;LOG_DIR&gt;/stderr";
```

**Step 4**

Compiling the request XML.

**NOTE**: my implementation requires a label on the AM container, so am-container-node-label-expression is added. This will not be applicable in all cases.

The mapping from the sparkConf to the REST request is (shown here in XML, JSON implementation is also supported):

```
<application-submission-context>
    <application-id>"+applicationId+"</application-id> 
    <application-name>"+appName+"</application-name>
    <queue>default</queue>
    <priority>0</priority>
    <am-container-spec>
       <local-resources>+localResources+</local-resources>
       <environment>
          <entry>
             <key>SPARK_YARN_STAGING_DIR</key>
             <value>"+hdfs+"/user/"+userName+"/.sparkStaging/"+applicationId+"</value>
          </entry>
          <entry>
             <key>CLASSPATH</key>
             <value>$PWD:$PWD/__spark_conf__:$PWD/__spark_libs__/*:/spark-non-hdfs-storage/spark-assembly-2.3.0-hadoop2.7/*:%HADOOP_CONF_DIR%:%HADOOP_COMMON_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/*:%HADOOP_COMMON_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:%HADOOP_HDFS_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:%HADOOP_HDFS_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:%HADOOP_YARN_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/*:%HADOOP_YARN_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:%HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:%HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$PWD/__spark_conf__/__hadoop_conf__</value>
          </entry>
          <entry>
             <key>SPARK_USER</key>
             <value>"+userName+"</value>
          </entry>
       </environment>
       <commands>
          <command>"+command+"</command>
       </commands>
    </am-container-spec>
    <unmanaged-AM>false</unmanaged-AM>
    <max-app-attempts>1</max-app-attempts>
    <resource>
      <memory>5632</memory>
      <vCores>1</vCores>
    </resource>
    <application-type>SPARK</application-type>
    <keep-containers-across-application-attempts>false</keep-containers-across-application-attempts>
    <application-tags>
      <tag>"+sparkYarnTag+"</tag>
    </application-tags>
    <am-container-node-label-expression>appMngr</am-container-node-label-expression>
    <log-aggregation-context/>
    <attempt-failures-validity-interval>1</attempt-failures-validity-interval>
    <reservation-id/>
</application-submission-context>
```

**Step 5:**

Submitting the application via REST http PUT:

```
private void submitApplication (String body, String userName) throws SMSparkManagerException {
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri+"?user.name="+userName);
    try {
        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, ContentType.APPLICATION_XML));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=202) {
            throw new SMSparkManagerException("The application could not be submitted to Yarn, response http code "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        logger.error("The application Could not be submitted due to UnsupportedEncodingException in the provided body: "+body, e );
        throw new SMSparkManagerException("Error in submitting application to yarn");
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        logger.error("The application Could not be submitted due to ClientProtocolException", e);
        throw new SMSparkManagerException("Error in submitting application to yarn");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("The application Could not be submitted due to IOException", e);
        throw new SMSparkManagerException("Error in submitting application to yarn");
    }
}
```